# `requestAnimationFrame` polyfill error in Jest tests

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-dom

Got this error after upgrading to React when I ran my Jest unit tests:

```
React depends on requestAnimationFrame. Make sure that you load a polyfill in older browsers.
```

How do I fix it?

I'm using Jest 18.1.0.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Found a workaround!

Steps:

1. Create the file `__mocks__/react.js` (see about [`__mocks__` folder here](https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks))
2. Add the following into `__mocks__/react.js`

```js
const react = require('react');
// Resolution for requestAnimationFrame not supported in jest error :
// https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/9102#issuecomment-283873039
global.window = global;
window.addEventListener = () => {};
window.requestAnimationFrame = () => {
  throw new Error('requestAnimationFrame is not supported in Node');
};

module.exports = react;
```

3. Run jest !

As marked on comments on the code

This is the solution from
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/9102#issuecomment-283873039

Comment: I use redux-observable and RxJs, I needed to add:

`window.cancelAnimationFrame = window.clearTimeout`
and `window.requestAnimationFrame = (cb) => window.setTimeout(cb, 1000 / 60)`

(I inspired from the code in RxJS)

Answer (score 35):

this worked for me:

1. Install `raf`

`npm install --saveDev raf` or `yarn add -D raf`

2. Add the polyfill to your `setupFiles` in your `jest` config in `package.json` like this:

`'setupFiles': ['raf/polyfill']`

Note: if you have other setup files in this array, you may want to put `raf/polyfill` first.

Comment: What and where are my setupFiles config?

Comment: @kirsteng it is one of the [jest config](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#setupfiles-array) property. Btw this solution works for me, cheers!

Comment: This is the solution found in other packages. https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/blob/master/package.json#L81—`raf` is also a dependency of `airbnb/enzyme`.

Answer (score 10):

If you just need to polyfill it for tests, then you don't actually need the throttling.

Create a new file with this code:

```
global.requestAnimationFrame = function (cb) {
    return setTimeout(cb, 0);
};
```

Add that file to the `jest/setupFiles` array in your package.json.

Comment: nice ... i dropped the `setTimeout` and went with just `cb()` - works for all of my existing tests.

Comment: i have added this to my setup file but still getting the warning.

Comment: @th1rdey3 in order to make work this the entry on `package.json` must be: `"jest": {
  "setupFiles": ["./someFolder/jestHelpers.js"]
 }`

Answer (score 8):

If you are using create-react-app, some of these solutions will not work well (or at all, in the case of `setupFiles`). What does work well is creating a file at `src/setupTests.js` and adding your mock in there:

```
global.requestAnimationFrame = (cb) => { cb(); };
```

You can also add other global mocks in there (e.g. `localStorage` and `navigator.serviceWorker`).

Answer (score 1):

Another working solution!

The idea is to load a simple shim before each spec, by using the setupFiles property in the jest config.

Create a file `shim.js` file (preferably in your root dir) and have this code in it:

```
global.requestAnimationFrame = (callback) => {
    setTimeout(callback, 0);
};
```

Next, you may be having redundant code that keep reappearing in all/most of your files - and you want to put them in a single file and have them run before each spec also, to do that:

Create a `setup.js` file in the root dir too. A good piece of redundant code to D.R.Y is the react enzyme adapter configuration code. Paste it here

```
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

Now create the `jest.config.js` file, to specify the paths of the two files

```
{
    module.exports = {
        "setupFiles": ["<rootDir>shim.js", "<rootDir>setup.js"]
    }
}
```

**N.B:** The jest config file take `json`, so make sure *json*'s in. Also, if your `shim.js` and `setup.js` files are not in the same dir as your `jest.config.js`, adjust the path accordingly.

Hope this helps!

Credit: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/4545

Answer (score 1):

Here's a realistic way to mock requestAnimationFrame:

```
let time;
const maxTimeElapsed = 2000;

beforeEach(() => {
  time = 0;
  jest.spyOn(window, 'requestAnimationFrame').mockImplementation(cb => {
    time += 100;
    if (time < maxTimeElapsed) {
      return cb(time) as any;
    }
  });
});
```

in your test, it repeatedly calls the RAF callback until it reaches the max elapsed time that you set. It happens instantly, so you don't need to stall it.

Answer (score 0):

Just upgrade your `react-scripts` to 1.0.15 or above. It has been officially fixed after that version. See more details in https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3199

Search the comment of `gaearon commented on 31 Oct 2017`

Answer (score 0):

If you use TypeScript, the best solution is;

```
window.requestAnimationFrame = (): number => {
   window.clearTimeout();
   return 0;
};
```

Before all your describe and test suits.

Answer (score 0):

According `raf` [package docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/raf#api) at this moment need to run `polyfill()` function and specify object that need to be polyfilled. In my case works:

```js
require('raf').polyfill(global.window)
```

Answer (score -1):

Turns out it was because I upgraded `enzyme` without upgrading `react` and `react-dom`.

React 15.5 brings about some deprecations that caused many dependent libraries to have to update too. Make sure you are updating `react`, `react-dom` and check the README of those dependent packages for new libraries you have to install. For instance, Enzyme 2.8.2 now requires `react-addons-test-utils` as a dependency.

Comment: I have upgraded react and react-dom but it seems not work.