React throwing TypeError: Cannot read property 'now' of undefined
I'm trying to update a legacy project to node 16, the project is a SSR react project with express.
Its using webpack 4..
The error just says: TypeError: Cannot read property 'now' of undefined
I dont know what is causing it and the error is very generic
I try update some main library like react, express, babel.. but it always the same error
EDIT 1: It is only breaking on build.
The stacktrace is:
his browser doesn't support requestAnimationFrame. Make sure that you load a polyfill in older browsers.
This browser doesn't support cancelAnimationFrame. Make sure that you load a polyfill in older browsers.
/Users/rafaela/Documents/Projects/highnote-frontend/dist-server/server.js:665
/var r,o,i,a,s;if("function"!=typeof MessageChannel){var c=null,l=null,u=function(){if(null!==c)try{var e=t.unstable_now();c(!0,e),c=null}catch(e){throw setTimeout(u,0),e}},d=Date.now();t.unstable_now=function(){return Date.now()-d},r=function(e){null!==c?setTimeout(r,0,e):(c=e,setTimeout(u,0))},o=function(e,t){l=setTimeout(e,t)},i=function(){clearTimeout(l)},a=function(){return!1},s=t.unstable_forceFrameRate=function(){}}else{var p=Object({location:Object({}),navigator:Object({})}).performance,f=Object({location:Object({}),navigator:Object({})}).Date,m=Object({location:Object({}),navigator:Object({})}).setTimeout,=Object({location:Object({}),navigator:Object({})}).clearTimeout;if("undefined"!=typeof console){var h=Object({location:Object({}),navigator:Object({})}).cancelAnimationFrame;"function"!=typeof Object({location:Object({}),navigator:Object({})}).requestAnimationFrame&&console.error("This browser doesn't support requestAnimationFrame. Make sure that you load a polyfill in older browsers.),"function"!=typeof h&&console.error("This browser doesn't support cancelAnimationFrame. Make sure that you load a polyfill in older browsers. )}if("object"==typeof p&&"function"==typeof p.now)t.unstable_now=function(){return p.now()};else{var g=f.now();t.unstable_now=function(){return f.now()-g}}var v=!1,b=null,y=-1,O=5,E=0;a=function(){return t.unstable_now()>=E},s=function(){},t.unstable_forceFrameRate=function(e){0>e||125<e?console.error("forceFrameRate takes a positive int between 0 and 125, forcing framerates higher than 125 fps is not unsupported"):O=0<e?Math.floor(1e3/e):5};var w=new MessageChannel,S=w.port2;w.port1.onmessage=function(){if(null!==b){var e=t.unstable_now();E=e+O;try{b(!0,e)?S.postMessage(null):(v=!1,b=null)}catch(e){throw S.postMessage(null),e}}else v=!1},r=function(e){b=e,v||(v=!0,S.postMessage(null))},o=function(e,n){y=m((function(){e(t.unstable_now())}),n)},i=function(){(y),y=-1}}function x(e,t){var n=e.length;e.push(t);e:for(;;){var r=n-1>>>1,o=e[r];if(!(void 0!==o&&0<C(o,t)))break e;e[r]=t,e[n]=o,n=r}}function A(e){return void 0===(e=e[0])?null:e}function L(e){var t=e[0];if(void 0!==t){var n=e.pop();if(n!==t){e[0]=n;e:for(var r=0,o=e.length;r<o;){var i=2(r+1)-1,a=e[i],s=i+1,c=e[s];if(void 0!==a&&0>C(a,n))void 0!==c&&0>C(c,a)?(e[r]=c,e[s]=n,r=s):(e[r]=a,e[i]=n,r=i);else{if(!(void 0!==c&&0>C(c,n)))break e;e[r]=c,e[s]=n,r=s}}}return t}return null}function C(e,t){var n=e.sortIndex-t.sortIndex;return 0!==n?n:e.id-t.id}var T=[],j=[],k=1,M=null,I=3,N=!1,D=!1,P=!1;function R(e){for(var t=A(j);null!==t;){if(null===t.callback)L(j);else{if(!(t.startTime<=e))break;L(j),t.sortIndex=t.expirationTime,x(T,t)}t=A(j)}}function F(e){if(P=!1,R(e),!D)if(null!==A(T))D=!0,r(Y);else{var t=A(j);null!==t&&o(F,t.startTime-e)}}function Y(e,n){D=!1,P&&(P=!1,i()),N=!0;var r=I;try{for(R(n),M=A(T);null!==M&&(!(M.expirationTime>n)||e&&!a());){var s=M.callback;if(null!==s){M.callback=null,I=M.priorityLevel;var c=s(M.expirationTime<=n);n=t.unstable_now(),"function"==typeof c?M.callback=c:M===A(T)&&L(T),R(n)}else L(T);M=A(T)}if(null!==M)var l=!0;else{var u=A(j);null!==u&&o(F,u.startTime-n),l=!1}return l}finally{M=null,I=r,N=!1}}function G(e){switch(e){case 1:return-1;case 2:return 250;case 5:return 1073741823;case 4:return 1e4;default:return 5e3}}var H=s;t.unstable_IdlePriority=5,t.unstable_ImmediatePriority=1,t.unstable_LowPriority=4,t.unstable_NormalPriority=3,t.unstable_Profiling=null,t.unstable_UserBlockingPriority=2,t.unstable_cancelCallback=function(e){e.callback=null},t.unstable_continueExecution=function(){D||N||(D=!0,r(Y))},t.unstable_getCurrentPriorityLevel=function(){return I},t.unstable_getFirstCallbackNode=function(){return A(T)},t.unstable_next=function(e){switch(I){case 1:case 2:case 3:var t=3;break;default:t=I}var n=I;I=t;try{return e()}finally{I=n}},t.unstable_pauseExecution=function(){},t.unstable_requestPaint=H,t.unstable_runWithPriority=function(e,t){switch(e){case 1:case 2:case 3:case 4:case 5:break;default:e=3}var n=I;I=e;try{return t()}finally{I=n}},t.unstable_scheduleCallback=function(e,n,a){var s=t.unstable_now();if("object"==typeof a&&null!==a){var c=a.delay;c="number"==typeof c&&0<c?s+c:s,a="number"==typeof a.timeout?a.timeout:G(e)}else a=G(e),c=s;return e={id:k++,callback:n,priorityLevel:e,startTime:c,expirationTime:a=c+a,sortIndex:-1},c>s?(e.sortIndex=c,x(j,e),null===A(T)&&e===A(j)&&(P?i():P=!0,o(F,c-s))):(e.sortIndex=a,x(T,e),D||N||(D=!0,r(Y))),e},t.unstable_shouldYield=function(){var e=t.unstable_now();R(e);var n=A(T);return n!==M&&null!==M&&null!==n&&null!==n.callback&&n.startTime<=e&&n.expirationTime<M.expirationTime||a()},t.unstable_wrapCallback=function(e){var t=I;return function(){var n=I;I=t;try{return e.apply(this,arguments)}finally{I=n}}}},function(e,t){(function(t){e.exports=t}).call(this,{})},function(e,t){function n(e,t){void 0!==e.serveStatic&&(t.serveStatic=e.serveStatic),function(e,t){var n=["cacheControl","dotfiles","etag","extensions","index","fallthrough","immutable","lastModified","maxAge","redirect","setHeaders"];for(var o in n){var i=n[o];void 0===e[i]||t.serveStatic&&void 0!==t.serveStatic[i]||r(t,i,e[i])}}(e,t)}function r(e,t,n){"object"!=typeof e.serveStatic&&(e.serveStatic={}),e.serveStatic[t]=n}function o(e){return void 0===e.indexFromEmptyFile&&void 0!==e.index?e.index:void 0===e.index&&void 0!==e.indexFromEmptyFile?e.indexFromEmptyFile:"index.html"}e.exports={sanitizeOptions:function(e){let t={index:o(e=e||{})};void 0!==e.enableBrotli&&(t.enableBrotli=!!e.enableBrotli);"object"==typeof e.customCompressions&&(t.customCompressions=e.customCompressions);"object"==typeof e.orderPreference&&(t.orderPreference=e.orderPreference);return n(e,t),t}}},function(e,t){e.exports={findEncoding:function(e,t,n){if(e){let r=e.split(",").map(e=>function(e){let t=e.split(";");try{if(t.length>1){const e=t[1].trim().match(/q=(.)/)[1];return{name:t[0].trim(),q:parseFloat(e)}}}catch(e){}return{name:t[0].trim(),q:1}}(e)).sort((e,t)=>t.q-e.q).filter(e=>e.q>0).map(e=>e.name);return r=function(e,t){if(!t||0===t.length)return e;for(let n=t.length-1;n>=0;n--){let r=t[n],o=e.indexOf(r);o>=0&&(e.splice(o,1),e.splice(0,0,r))}return e}(r,n),function(e,t){for(const n of e){if("identity"===n)return null;for(let e of t)if(""===n||n===e.encodingName)return e}return null}(r,t)}return null}}},function(e,t,n){"use strict";function r(e){return e&&"object"==typeof e&&"default"in e?e.default:e}var o=n(0),i=r(o),a=r(n(894));function s(e,t,n){return t in e?Object.defineProperty(e,t,{value:n,enumerable:!0,configurable:!0,writable:!0}):e[t]=n,e}var c=!(!Object({location:Object({}),navigator:Object({})}).document||!Object({location:Object({}),navigator:Object({})}).document.createElement);e.exports=function(e,t,n){if("function"!=typeof e)throw new Error("Expected reducePropsToState to be a function.");if("function"!=typeof t)throw new Error("Expected handleStateChangeOnClient to be a function.");if(void 0!==n&&"function"!=typeof n)throw new Error("Expected mapStateOnServer to either be undefined or a function.");return function(r){if("function"!=typeof r)throw new Error("Expected WrappedComponent to be a React component.");var l,u=[];function d(){l=e(u.map((function(e){return e.props}))),p.canUseDOM?t(l):n&&(l=n(l))}var p=function(e){var t,n;function o(){return e.apply(this,arguments)||this}n=e,(t=o).prototype=Object.create(n.prototype),t.prototype.constructor=t,t.proto=n,o.peek=function(){return l},o.rewind=function(){if(o.canUseDOM)throw new Error("You may only call rewind() on the server. Call peek() to read the current state.");var e=l;return l=void 0,u=[],e};var s=o.prototype;return s.shouldComponentUpdate=function(e){return!a(e,this.props)},s.componentWillMount=function(){u.push(this),d()},s.componentDidUpdate=function(){d()},s.componentWillUnmount=function(){var e=u.indexOf(this);u.splice(e,1),d()},s.render=function(){return i.createElement(r,this.props)},o}(o.Component);return s(p,"displayName","SideEffect("+function(e){return e.displayName||e.name||"Component"}(r)+")"),s(p,"canUseDOM",c),p}}},function(e,t){e.exports=function(e,t,n,r){var o=n?n.call(r,e,t):void 0;if(void 0!==o)return!!o;if(e===t)return!0;if("object"!=typeof e||!e||"object"!=typeof t||!t)return!1;var i=Object.keys(e),a=Object.keys(t);if(i.length!==a.length)return!1;for(var s=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.bind(t),c=0;c<i.length;c++){var l=i[c];if(!s(l))return!1;var u=e[l],d=t[l];if(!1===(o=n?n.call(r,u,d,l):void 0)||void 0===o&&u!==d)return!1}return!0}},function(e,t,n){t.__esModule=!0,t.warn=t.requestAnimationFrame=t.reducePropsToState=t.mapStateOnServer=t.handleClientStateChange=t.convertReactPropstoHtmlAttributes=void 0;var r="function"==typeof Symbol&&"symbol"==typeof Symbol.iterator?function(e){return typeof e}:function(e){return e&&"function"==typeof Symbol&&e.constructor===Symbol&&e!==Symbol.prototype?"symbol":typeof e},o=Object.assign||function(e){for(var t=1;t<arguments.length;t++){var n=arguments[t];for(var r in n)Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(n,r)&&(e[r]=n[r])}return e},i=c(n(0)),a=c(n(104)),s=n(519);function c(e){return e&&e.__esModule?e:{default:e}}var l,u=function(e){var t=!(arguments.length>1&&void 0!==arguments[1])||arguments[1];return!1===t?String(e):String(e).replace(/&/g,"&").replace(/</g,"<").replace(/>/g,">").replace(/"/g,""").replace(/'/g,"'")},d=function(e){var t=h(e,s.TAG_NAMES.TITLE),n=h(e,s.HELMET_PROPS.TITLE_TEMPLATE);if(n&&t)return n.replace(/%s/g,(function(){return t}));var r=h(e,s.HELMET_PROPS.DEFAULT_TITLE);return t||r||void 0},p=function(e){return h(e,s.HELMET_PROPS.ON_CHANGE_CLIENT_STATE)||function(){}},f=function(e,t){return t.filter((function(t){return void 0!==t[e]})).map((function(t){return t[e]})).reduce((function(e,t){return o({},e,t)}),{})},m=function(e,t){return t.filter((function(e){return void 0!==e[s.TAG_NAMES.BASE]})).map((function(e){return e[s.TAG_NAMES.BASE]})).reverse().reduce((function(t,n){if(!t.length)for(var r=Object.keys(n),o=0;o<r.length;o++){var i=r[o].toLowerCase();if(-1!==e.indexOf(i)&&n[i])return t.concat(n)}return t}),[])},=function(e,t,n){var o={};return n.filter((function(t){return!!Array.isArray(t[e])||(void 0!==t[e]&&y("Helmet: "+e+' should be of type "Array". Instead found type "'+r(t[e])+'"'),!1)})).map((function(t){return t[e]})).reverse().reduce((function(e,n){var r={};n.filter((function(e){for(var n=void 0,i=Object.keys(e),a=0;a<i.length;a++){var c=i[a],l=c.toLowerCase();-1===t.indexOf(l)||n===s.TAG_PROPERTIES.REL&&"canonical"===e[n].toLowerCase()||l===s.TAG_PROPERTIES.REL&&"stylesheet"===e[l].toLowerCase()||(n=l),-1===t.indexOf(c)||c!==s.TAG_PROPERTIES.INNER_HTML&&c!==s.TAG_PROPERTIES.CSS_TEXT&&c!==s.TAG_PROPERTIES.ITEM_PROP||(n=c)}if(!n||!e[n])return!1;var u=e[n].toLowerCase();return o[n]||(o[n]={}),r[n]||(r[n]={}),!o[n][u]&&(r[n][u]=!0,!0)})).reverse().forEach((function(t){return e.push(t)}));for(var i=Object.keys(r),c=0;c<i.length;c++){var l=i[c],u=(0,a.default)({},o[l],r[l]);o[l]=u}return e}),[]).reverse()},h=function(e,t){for(var n=e.length-1;n>=0;n--){var r=e[n];if(r.hasOwnProperty(t))return r[t]}return null},g=(l=Date.now(),function(e){var t=Date.now();t-l>16?(l=t,e(t)):setTimeout((function(){g(e)}),0)}),v=Object({location:Object({}),navigator:Object({})}).requestAnimationFrame||Object({location:Object({}),navigator:Object({})}).webkitRequestAnimationFrame||Object({location:Object({}),navigator:Object({})}).mozRequestAnimationFrame||g,b=Object({location:Object({}),navigator:Object({})}).cancelAnimationFrame||Object({location:Object({}),navigator:Object({})}).webkitCancelAnimationFrame||Object({location:Object({}),navigator:Object({})}).mozCancelAnimationFrame||function(e){return clearTimeout(e)},y=function(e){return console&&"function"==typeof console.warn&&console.warn(e)},O=null,E=function(e,t){var n=e.baseTag,r=e.bodyAttributes,o=e.htmlAttributes,i=e.linkTags,a=e.metaTags,c=e.noscriptTags,l=e.onChangeClientState,u=e.scriptTags,d=e.styleTags,p=e.title,f=e.titleAttributes;x(s.TAG_NAMES.BODY,r),x(s.TAG_NAMES.HTML,o),S(p,f);var m={baseTag:A(s.TAG_NAMES.BASE,n),linkTags:A(s.TAG_NAMES.LINK,i),metaTags:A(s.TAG_NAMES.META,a),noscriptTags:A(s.TAG_NAMES.NOSCRIPT,c),scriptTags:A(s.TAG_NAMES.SCRIPT,u),styleTags:A(s.TAG_NAMES.STYLE,d)},={},h={};Object.keys(m).forEach((function(e){var t=m[e],n=t.newTags,r=t.oldTags;n.length&&([e]=n),r.length&&(h[e]=m[e].oldTags)})),t&&t(),l(e,,h)},w=function(e){return Array.isArray(e)?e.join(""):e},S=function(e,t){void 0!==e&&document.title!==e&&(document.title=w(e)),x(s.TAG_NAMES.TITLE,t)},x=function(e,t){var n=document.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];if(n){for(var r=n.getAttribute(s.HELMET_ATTRIBUTE),o=r?r.split(","):[],i=[].concat(o),a=Object.keys(t),c=0;c<a.length;c++){var l=a[c],u=t[l]||"";n.getAttribute(l)!==u&&n.setAttribute(l,u),-1===o.indexOf(l)&&o.push(l);var d=i.indexOf(l);-1!==d&&i.splice(d,1)}for(var p=i.length-1;p>=0;p--)n.removeAttribute(i[p]);o.length===i.length?n.removeAttribute(s.HELMET_ATTRIBUTE):n.getAttribute(s.HELMET_ATTRIBUTE)!==a.join(",")&&n.setAttribute(s.HELMET_ATTRIBUTE,a.join(","))}},A=function(e,t){var n=document.head||document.querySelector(s.TAG_NAMES.HEAD),r=n.querySelectorAll(e+"["+s.HELMET_ATTRIBUTE+"]"),o=Array.prototype.slice.call(r),i=[],a=void 0;return t&&t.length&&t.forEach((function(t){var n=document.createElement(e);for(var r in t)if(t.hasOwnProperty(r))if(r===s.TAG_PROPERTIES.INNER_HTML)n.innerHTML=t.innerHTML;else if(r===s.TAG_PROPERTIES.CSS_TEXT)n.styleSheet?n.styleSheet.cssText=t.cssText:n.appendChild(document.createTextNode(t.cssText));else{var c=void 0===t[r]?"":t[r];n.setAttribute(r,c)}n.setAttribute(s.HELMET_ATTRIBUTE,"true"),o.some((function(e,t){return a=t,n.isEqualNode(e)}))?o.splice(a,1):i.push(n)})),o.forEach((function(e){return e.parentNode.removeChild(e)})),i.forEach((function(e){return n.appendChild(e)})),{oldTags:o,newTags:i}},L=function(e){return Object.keys(e).reduce((function(t,n){var r=void 0!==e[n]?n+'="'+e[n]+'"':""+n;return t?t+" "+r:r}),"")},C=function(e){var t=arguments.length>1&&void 0!==arguments[1]?arguments[1]:{};return Object.keys(e).reduce((function(t,n){return t[s.REACT_TAG_MAP[n]||n]=e[n],t}),t)},T=function(e,t,n){switch(e){case s.TAG_NAMES.TITLE:return{toComponent:function(){return e=t.title,n=t.titleAttributes,(r={key:e})[s.HELMET_ATTRIBUTE]=!0,o=C(n,r),[i.default.createElement(s.TAG_NAMES.TITLE,o,e)];var e,n,r,o},toString:function(){return function(e,t,n,r){var o=L(n),i=w(t);return o?"<"+e+" "+s.HELMET_ATTRIBUTE+'="true" '+o+">"+u(i,r)+"</"+e+">":"<"+e+" "+s.HELMET_ATTRIBUTE+'="true">'+u(i,r)+"</"+e+">"}(e,t.title,t.titleAttributes,n)}};case s.ATTRIBUTE_NAMES.BODY:case s.ATTRIBUTE_NAMES.HTML:return{toComponent:function(){return C(t)},toString:function(){return L(t)}};default:return{toComponent:function(){return function(e,t){return t.map((function(t,n){var r,o=((r={key:n})[s.HELMET_ATTRIBUTE]=!0,r);return Object.keys(t).forEach((function(e){var n=s.REACT_TAG_MAP[e]||e;if(n===s.TAG_PROPERTIES.INNER_HTML||n===s.TAG_PROPERTIES.CSS_TEXT){var r=t.innerHTML||t.cssText;o.dangerouslySetInnerHTML={__html:r}}else o[n]=t[e]})),i.default.createElement(e,o)}))}(e,t)},toString:function(){return function(e,t,n){return t.reduce((function(t,r){var o=Object.keys(r).filter((function(e){return!(e===s.TAG_PROPERTIES.INNER_HTML||e===s.TAG_PROPERTIES.CSS_TEXT)})).reduce((function(e,t){var o=void 0===r[t]?t:t+'="'+u(r[t],n)+'"';return e?e+" "+o:o}),""),i=r.innerHTML||r.cssText||"",a=-1===s.SELF_CLOSING_TAGS.indexOf(e);return t+"<"+e+" "+s.HELMET_ATTRIBUTE+'="true" '+o+(a?"/>":">"+i+"</"+e+">")}),"")}(e,t,n)}}}};t.convertReactPropstoHtmlAttributes=function(e){var t=arguments.length>1&&void 0!==arguments[1]?arguments[1]:{};return Object.keys(e).reduce((function(t,n){return t[s.HTML_TAG_MAP[n]||n]=e[n],t}),t)},t.handleClientStateChange=function(e){O&&b(O),e.defer?O=v((function(){E(e,(function(){O=null}))})):(E(e),O=null)},t.mapStateOnServer=function(e){var t=e.baseTag,n=e.bodyAttributes,r=e.encode,o=e.htmlAttributes,i=e.linkTags,a=e.metaTags,c=e.noscriptTags,l=e.scriptTags,u=e.styleTags,d=e.title,p=void 0===d?"":d,f=e.titleAttributes;return{base:T(s.TAG_NAMES.BASE,t,r),bodyAttributes:T(s.ATTRIBUTE_NAMES.BODY,n,r),htmlAttributes:T(s.ATTRIBUTE_NAMES.HTML,o,r),link:T(s.TAG_NAMES.LINK,i,r),meta:T(s.TAG_NAMES.META,a,r),noscript:T(s.TAG_NAMES.NOSCRIPT,c,r),script:T(s.TAG_NAMES.SCRIPT,l,r),style:T(s.TAG_NAMES.STYLE,u,r),title:T(s.TAG_NAMES.TITLE,{title:p,titleAttributes:f},r)}},t.reducePropsToState=function(e){return{baseTag:m([s.TAG_PROPERTIES.HREF],e),bodyAttributes:f(s.ATTRIBUTE_NAMES.BODY,e),defer:h(e,s.HELMET_PROPS.DEFER),encode:h(e,s.HELMET_PROPS.ENCODE_SPECIAL_CHARACTERS),htmlAttributes:f(s.ATTRIBUTE_NAMES.HTML,e),linkTags:(s.TAG_NAMES.LINK,[s.TAG_PROPERTIES.REL,s.TAG_PROPERTIES.HREF],e),metaTags:(s.TAG_NAMES.META,[s.TAG_PROPERTIES.NAME,s.TAG_PROPERTIES.CHARSET,s.TAG_PROPERTIES.HTTPEQUIV,s.TAG_PROPERTIES.PROPERTY,s.TAG_PROPERTIES.ITEM_PROP],e),noscriptTags:(s.TAG_NAMES.NOSCRIPT,[s.TAG_PROPERTIES.INNER_HTML],e),onChangeClientState:p(e),scriptTags:(s.TAG_NAMES.SCRIPT,[s.TAG_PROPERTIES.SRC,s.TAG_PROPERTIES.INNER_HTML],e),styleTags:_(s.TAG_NAMES.STYLE,[s.TAG_PROPERTIES.CSS_TEXT],e),title:d(e),titleAttributes:f(s.ATTRIBUTE_NAMES.TITLE,e)}},t.requestAnimationFrame=v,t.warn=y},function(e,t,n){"use strict";
TypeError: Cannot read property 'now' of undefined
at Object. (/Users/rafaela/Documents/Projects/highnote-frontend/dist-server/server.js:665:1324)
at o (/Users/rafaela/Documents/Projects/highnote-frontend/dist-server/server.js:1:126)
at Object. (/Users/rafaela/Documents/Projects/highnote-frontend/dist-server/server.js:657:117310)
at o (/Users/rafaela/Documents/Projects/highnote-frontend/dist-server/server.js:1:126)
at Object. (/Users/rafaela/Documents/Projects/highnote-frontend/dist-server/server.js:657:26)
at o (/Users/rafaela/Documents/Projects/highnote-frontend/dist-server/server.js:1:126)
at Object. (/Users/rafaela/Documents/Projects/highnote-frontend/dist-server/server.js:19:31788)
at o (/Users/rafaela/Documents/Projects/highnote-frontend/dist-server/server.js:1:126)
at Object. (/Users/rafaela/Documents/Projects/highnote-frontend/dist-server/server.js:6:67084)
at o (/Users/rafaela/Documents/Projects/highnote-frontend/dist-server/server.js:1:126)
Nothing much to say on the stacktrace, my server is:


app.use(cookieParser())
app.set('trust proxy', true)
app.use(morgan('combined'))
app.use(express.json())

app.use(
  contentSecurityPolicy({
    useDefaults: true,
    directives: CSP_CONFIG,
    reportOnly: false,
  })
)

app.use('/static', expressStaticGzip('dist'))


const getAppHtml = (newStore, props) => 
renderToString(
  <Provider store={configureStore(newStore)}>
    <RouterContext {...props} />
  </Provider>
)

const renderBaseHTML = (appHtml, store, hasNoIndex = false) =>
  baseHtml(appHtml, store, assetsPaths, Helmet.rewind(), hasNoIndex)

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  const theDate = new Date()
  let redirectTo
  let receivedUrl

  try {
    match(
      { routes: routes(configureStore(initialState)), location: req.url },
      (err, redirect, props) => {
        if (redirect && !err) {
          res.redirect(redirect.pathname + redirect.search)
          return
        }
      
          const appHtml = getAppHtml(initialState, props)

          res.status(getStatus(err, props)).send(renderBaseHTML(appHtml, initialState))
        
      }
    )
  } catch (e) {
    console.warn('render error:\n', e, '\n\n')
    res.status(500).send(baseHtml('', {}, assetsPaths))
  }


})

app.listen(port, err => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err)
    return
  }

  console.info('[Production] App is running on port', port)
})



EDIT 2: I followed the suggestion removing everything I could until the server built and started it. However, I'm now encountering this error:
Error: Minified React error #130; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=130&args[]=object&args[]= for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
I simplified my app to just a hello world component:
import React from 'react';

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello world</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

I believe the issue is related to how I import the components because when I import like this:
import { App } from '_view/app';

it works.
import App from '_view/app';

but not this
But I'm not sure why this is happening, if there's like a babel or something to convert this in order to not go over the whole app change imports

So, this is a Null Pointer Error. You probably know that. The question is, what is causing some object to be null instead of the thing it is supposed to be. I don't know, but let me suggest the following: post the full stacktrace of the error, and post your code. In fact, do this fairly quickly. There are people here on StackOverflow who will downvote your question for lacking these things. Once you have given us more context, we may be able to help you.

Hey, thanks for the response. I've added an edit with more information. Hope it helps!

I don't have nodeJS on my work computer, so I can't check this, but here are some possibilities: 1> you may need to import Date. I see the code calling Date.now, and if Date is not available, that is possible. 2> you may need to address the polyfill error.  see second and third answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43604058/requestanimationframe-polyfill-error-in-jest-tests

You can also just try commenting out lots of lines, down to the bare minimum, to see if it will work, then add lines back one at a time to see where it crashes.
